# Error caught while saving metrics to the database

Tags: hibernate

I am getting the below exception some times, but not every time. Any clue about the resolution, please do share.

Thanks in advance.

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryTimeoutException: could not insert: 
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:645)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.translateException(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:160)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:148)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
        at
```

Comment: Can you put your code, so we can help.

Comment: And include the full stacktrace.  what you've provided is not helpful.